# swiftmailer :: send virtual file?

Tags: email, file, swiftmailer

I am sending an email to an api that gets its content from an attached file.

I do not want to actually create the file (its like one line of text) and then attach it and send it.

Is it possible to create a filestream and send that through swiftmailer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out [Swiftmailer supports Dynamic Attachments](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/dynamic-attachments).

The basic idea is:

```
//Create your content in a variable.
$content = "Hi there\r\nHow are you";

//Create a Swiftmailer attachment
//specify the data, filename, mimetype
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($content, 'my-file.pdf', 'application/pdf');

//attach the file
$message->attach($attachment);
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: +1 glad you figured it out, and I'll check this out in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I have always had to create the file and then attach it with SwiftMailer.

Though you can `unlink()` the file as soon as the email has been sent.

Comment: Well then good news, I found the answer: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/dynamic-attachments